# Scrollbar in tkinter is displaying but is not active

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm trying to build a simple file manager in tkinter. The approach I came up with is to get a list of all the files in the directory, and then iterate through said list to create a series of buttons connected to a dropdown menu with some options. I then put those buttons in a frame, and the frame in a canvas, and connect the canvas to the scrollbar.

The scrollbar is there visually, but it's not active or something. Also, if you think I've used the wrong approach please let me know, I'd be very grateful

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

class FileManager:
    """semplice filemanager dotato delle funzionalità più essenziali"""
    def __init__(self):

        self.current_working_directory = "C:/Users/efede/OneDrive/Desktop/sto cazzo"

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("File Manager")

        self.main_frame = Frame(self.window)
        self.main_frame.pack()

        self.return_files_from_directory()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def return_files_from_directory(self):

        file_list = os.listdir(self.current_working_directory)

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.main_frame, orient="vertical")
        canvas = Canvas(self.main_frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="x")
        buttons_frame = Frame(self.main_frame)

        for el in file_list:

            file_button = Menubutton(buttons_frame, text=el, width=50, relief="raised")
            options_menu = Menu(file_button, tearoff=False)
            options_menu.add_command(label="copia", command=lambda button=file_button: self.copia(button))
            options_menu.add_command(label="elimina", command=lambda button=file_button: self.elimina(button))
            file_button["menu"] = options_menu

            def popup(event, options_menu=options_menu):# anche qui options_menu=options_menu
                options_menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

            file_button.bind("<Button-1>", popup)

            file_button.pack()

        canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=buttons_frame, anchor="nw")
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        # canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.configure(command=canvas.yview)
```

type here

```
    def copia(self, button):
        pass
        
    def elimina(self, button):
        nome_file = button["text"]
        path = f"{self.current_working_directory}/{nome_file}"
        try:
            os.remove(path)
            print(f"file {path} rimosso")
            messagebox.showinfo("File eliminato", f"file {path} rimosso con successo")
        except:
            print(f"file {path} non trovato")
            messagebox.showinfo("Errore", f"file {path} non trovato")
        self.return_files_from_directory()

    def crea_directory(self):
        pass

file_manager = FileManager()
file_manager
```

Comment: Can you please try to reduce the size of your code? Since the problem is with creating a scrollable list of buttons, we don't need the functions that the buttons call, you can just set the `command` option to `None` for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do to debug this is to verify that you're setting `scrollregion` to an appropriate value. In this case, you're not. The reason is that until the frame is actually rendered on the screen the size will be 1x1 pixels.

The most common solution is to configure it so that the `scrollregion` is updated whenever the frame changes size. You can do that by binding to the `configure` method of the frame. When the frame is rendered, it's size will be adjusted by tkinter, the binding will fire, and the `scrollregion` will be adjusted.

The advantage to doing it this way is that if you add additional widgets to the frame at a later date, the `scrollregion` will automatically update without having to remember to do that later.

```
buttons_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
)
```